Change line length between parent/child in forest
Consider the following forest:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
    for tree={fork sep=2mm,
      grow=east,
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
      align=center,
      anchor=base west,
      l sep=4mm
    }
    [Main Branch, rotate=90, child anchor=north, parent anchor=south, anchor=center, l sep+=2mm, for children={fork sep+=2mm}
        [Hello1
            [Hello2]
            [Hello3]
        ]
        [Hello4
            [Hello5]
            [VeryVeryVeryLongHello6]
            [Hello7,
                [,coordinate,l=4.5cm,yshift=0.76mm,
                        [NormalHello1]
                        [NormalHello2]
                ]
            ]
            [VeryVeryVeryLongHello8]
            [Hello9]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}

This produces the following figure:

What I don't like about this tree is that the lines of NormalHello2 and NormalHello1 on the west side are too long when compared to the rest of the children in the tree.
The end result should look something like this:


Increase l sep for the parent node and increase fork sep for the children by the same amount. You don't need the extra coordinate node.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
    for tree={fork sep=2mm,
      grow=east,
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
      align=center,
      anchor=base west,
      l sep=4mm
    }
    [Main Branch, rotate=90, child anchor=north, parent anchor=south, anchor=center, l sep+=2mm, for children={fork sep+=2mm}
        [Hello1
            [Hello2]
            [Hello3]
        ]
        [Hello4
            [Hello5]
            [VeryVeryVeryLongHello6]
            [Hello7, l sep+=3.2cm, for children={fork sep+=3.2cm}
                        [NormalHello1]
                        [NormalHello2]
            ]
            [VeryVeryVeryLongHello8]
            [Hello9]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


Amazing. Thank you so much!

@JohnDoe You can make the code a bit faster if you use ' when changing e.g. dimensions etc. if they are provided by forest rather than tikz.
